# dateFromString returns the wrong date

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-mm-dd";
    NSDate *cDate = [formatter dateFromString:thisLine];
    NSLog(@"cDate '%@'  thisLine '%@'", cDate, thisLine);
```

NSLog prints:
cDate '2011-01-10 05:07:00 +0000'  thisLine '2011-07-10'
while cDate should be '2011-07-10'

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`NSDate` description](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will always print the date with its own formatting, generally for the `+000` time zone. You need to use the date format to get the correctly formatted date and use [MM for month not mm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *cDate = [formatter dateFromString:thisLine];
NSLog(@"cDate '%@'  thisLine '%@'", [formatter stringFromDate:cDate], thisLine);
```

> -(NSString*)description
>   **Discussion**
>  The representation is not guaranteed to remain
>   constant across different releases of the operating system. To format
>   a date, you should use a date formatter object instead (see
>   NSDateFormatter and Data Formatting Guide)

Comment: Please explain the -1 the OP I addressed both the formatting issue and the date specifier issue.

Comment: The problem isn't the printing format, it is that the month isn't being set to 7.

Comment: @SSteve yes but the OP did not specify which one and I did address both. OP said he expected  '2011-07-10' so there are 2 parts

Comment: You are correct. I missed that. I shouldn't do this before coffee. :-) I tried to upvote but it won't let me unless the answer is edited. If you want an upvote, make an edit (maybe put the MM note after the `description` excerpt) and I will do so. My apologies.

Comment: @SSteve I did edit and I needed to improve my answer any way, no problem and thanks

Answer (score 12):

Lowercase `mm` is for minutes not months, month use uppercase `MM`:

```
   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    NSDate *cDate = [formatter dateFromString:thisLine];
    NSLog(@"cDate '%@'  thisLine '%@'", cDate, thisLine);
```

Comment: that explains everything! thnx!